# Finding the smallest composition of a natural number with limited basic set of summands

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory

W.l.o.g. I have a set of natural numbers
$$S = \{s_1, \ldots, s_n\}, \quad s_i \in \mathbb N$$
as well as an $x \in \mathbb N$ I would like to express as sum of $s_i$.

> How do I find the smallest number of summands?

In other terms: How to find $\min{\{\lvert I \rvert: I \in \mathcal I\}} \subset \mathbb N$.

$$\mathcal I = \{I \in \mathcal P(S): \sum_{s_i \in I} s_i = x\}$$

**Hint**: The naive ansatz to start with the biggest $s_i$ that is just smaller/equal $x$ and continue with $x-k \cdot s_i$, $k\in \mathbb N$ fails as you can see with: $S = \{2, 5, 9\}$ and $x = 10$.

---

**Edit**: The notation states a set of distinct summands—and neglects the question of existence of such a partition—but I'd be interested in approaches for non-distinct $s_i$ as well. :-)

Comment: This is so general that I think the best you can hope for is an efficient algorithm.

Comment: That would also help me. :-)

Comment: For me the "naive" approach would be to check if the target can be expressed as one summand, as two summands, etc.  Stop if the target is obtained successfully, or if the $k$ smallest entries exceed the target, with failure.

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

1. You can use a summand more than once.
2. The $s_i$ are in increasing order.

Notation:
Define $M(x)$ as the minimum number of summands that you can use to add up to $x$. For convenience, define $M(0) = 0$.

Claims: (proof left to reader; there is a bit of cheat in here that some numbers may not be representable, so it is best to assume that $s_1=1$.)

1. $M(x) = 1 + min \{M(x-s_i)\}$, where the minimum is taken over all $i$ with $s_i <= x$
2. THIS STATEMENT IS INCORRECT (please see comment below) $M(x) = s_{n-1} + M(x-s_{n-1} s_n)$ for all $x \ge s_{n-1}s_n$

From an algorithmic perspective, if your numbers are not too large, you can pre-compute $M(x)$ for $x \in \{1\ldots s_{n-1}s_n\}$, using the second claim to take care of larger numbers. If this gets too large to store, then you need to look at some sort of time-memory trade-off in computation.

Comment: A strict interpretation of the OP's notation would mean that all summands are distinct.

Comment: I agree. However, the example used by the OP clearly is aiming to represent 10 as 5+5, so I assumed that was the problem the OP had in mind. Apologies if I assumed incorrectly.

Comment: Everything's fine. :-) I had both in my head and guess that I was too careless when I made up the example.
Claim 1 is a point I can definitely work with. I'm gonna edit it slightly to make the idea behind it more clear.

Comment: I don't get the idea behind Claim 2. You clearly had something with square numbers in mind since you used $s_{n-1}$ but in this form, it is wrong.
Try: $M(20) = 5 + M(-25) \neq 3$ (9+9+2)

Comment: I think it's OK, since it should only work for $x \gt s_{n-1} \times s_n$, which would be 45 in this example. Since 9 is the biggest of the numbers, all this is noting is that the best way to make 45 is five 9's, which is always true for the largest two numbers in your summand set.

Comment: Thought about this some more, and I may be misremembering. There is some rule like this that holds true, but the limit may be bigger that $s_{n-1} \times s_n$.

Comment: Now I remember! The key observation is that $M(x) \ge \lfloor{\frac{x}{s_n}}\rfloor$; this is just another way of saying that the biggest number you can represent with $k$ summands is $ks_n$. With this observation, it is not hard to show that there exists some limit $Z$ such that for all $x \ge Z$, $M(x) = 1+M(x-s_n)$; that is, beyond some value every minimal representation has to use at least one $s_n$. Back of the envelope calculation (assuming $s_1$ = 1) suggests that $Z = \frac{s_ns_{n-1}z}{s_n-s_{n-1}}$ works, where $z = max \{M(x)\}, x \in \{1\ldots s_n-1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the summands are drawn from a finite set $\{s_1,s_2,\ldots,s_n\}$ of positive integers, and that these may be repeated as often as desired, the problem of finding a shortest "addition chain" that reaches a given target $t$ can be formulated as an integer programming problem:

$$ \min X = x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_n $$

subject to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i s_i = t$ and non-negativity of integers $x_i \ge 0$.

As Jeremy Dover pointed out, it is expeditious to remove any common factor of all the potential summands $s_i$, since for the target $t$ to be expressed as such a summation, that common factor must divide $t$, and furthermore removing the common factor from $t$ and each $s_i$ reduces the solution to a case where the $s_i$ collectively have greatest common factor $1$.

Such a formulation does not immediately guarantee an efficient algorithm since as a class, [integer programming problems are NP-hard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming).  However it helps put in perspective some of the ideas for finding solutions.

The LP-relaxation of this problem (allowing for non-integer $x_i$'s) is easily solved by setting $x_i = t/s_i$ for the largest of the $s_i$'s and other unknowns to zero.  This is essentially the idea that motivates the OP's "naive ansatz".  We will henceforth assume for simplicity the $s_i$'s are ordered, so that $s_n$ is the largest of these.

In practice it may be straightforward to fix up such a non-integer solution to give one having all integer values $x_i$.  If a solution exists, we must have:

$$ \sum_{i\lt n} x_i s_i \equiv t \bmod{s_n} $$

In this vein we may look for the solution to our original problem by trying to solve the smaller problem of expressing a target $t-ms_n$ as a shortest summation with (repeated) summands from $S\setminus \{s_n\}$.  Choosing a felicitous integer value for $m\ge 0$ will produce the solution of our original problem, taking $x_n = m$ and other $x_i$ as found in the reduced problem.

Readers may find it convenient to think of searching for the solution working "backward" from target $t$ by a succession of "shortest paths" defined by edges that subtract an $s_i \lt s_n$ until a multiple $ms_n$ of $s_n$ is reached.  A best solution minimizes the combined sum of the length of path and $m$, since this will in turn be the sum of the $x_i$'s in the original problem.  Among shortest paths that reach a multiple of $s_n$ having a specific length, the best is the one that reduces $t$ the most (and thus gives the least $m$).

Note that the version of the problem in which summands may be repeated as many times as desired is the [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem), and the procedure we just outlined is easily related to a dynamic-programming approach to that.

---

Next let us consider the version in which summands are distinct and may only be used once.  This is a version of the classic [Subset Sum Problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) since we seek a *smallest* subset of $S$ that sums to $t$.  These decision problems alone (does a subset with the target sum exist?) are NP-complete.

Readers may again find it convenient to think in terms of a shortest path formulation.  Starting from target $t$ we attempt to find the shortest path to zero along edges that subtract an allowed summand $s_i$.  This graph path problem is simplified by the application of [Hobson's choice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hobson%27s_choice), since we either use the summand $s_i$ once or never at all.  Declining to use $s_i$ at some point in our search tree entitles us never to reconsider using it at a subsequent point in the search tree, although we may "backtrack" to that point and reconsider, as [iterative deepening of depth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search) is used to simulate [breadth-first search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

A very similar Question, [An algorithm to find $X$ numbers that sum up to a given value](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/842848/an-algorithm-to-find-x-numbers-that-sum-up-to-a-given-value), was asked in $2014$.

Assume as before that the possible summands $s_i$ have been sorted.  For small values of $X$, the (minimum) number of summands used, it is well-known that for $X=1$ there is an optimal solution by binary search in $O(\ln n)$ and for $X=2$ by a variant of [saddleback search](http://cs.geneseo.edu/~baldwin/math-thinking/saddleback.html) in $O(n)$.

The best known algorithm for the Subset Sum Problem, which does not promise a subset of smallest size but only a *decision* if a subset sum equals the target, is that of [Koiliaris and Xu(2015)](https://arxiv.org/abs/1507.02318), "A Faster Pseudopolynomial Time Algorithm for Subset Sum", which has complexity $O(t\sqrt{n})$.